# Can i add a string including baselinealignments programmatically to a textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working with VS2015 and WPF on a WPF-app with dynamic forms.
On my WPF windows i got some textblocks to which i want to add at runtime programmatically and dynamically a text (is it really the text?) like "51x4 + 4" per example.
When i try to set the string in the text-property at runtime i can only see the given string.

But when i add it in the content of the textblock in XAML i can see at runtime that the first "4" is subscripted.
Here the hardcoded example:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Height="50">
        5x<Run BaselineAlignment="Subscript">4</Run> + 4
</TextBlock>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add `Run` elements to the `Inlines` property of the `TextBlock`:

```
txt.Inlines.Add(new Run("5x"));
txt.Inlines.Add(new Run("4") { BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript });
txt.Inlines.Add(new Run(" + 4"));
```

Comment: Once again thank You very much mm8. I tried it and it works perfectly. Because i'm using the textblock inside a custom control i had to find out, how to access parts of custom controls. This site gave me a good example and i hope i can implement it now in my custom control: http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-part-names